# Is there a way to trigger another PR to a different branch when a PR is approved?

Tags: github

I have submitted PR to branch A. Once this approved, I need another PR to be automatically submitted to branch B. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No that makes little sense to have such behavior done automatically. But you still can open a new PR with the same branch (if it has not been rebased the on the 1st target branch) and target another branch for merging.